# A question on the error term in the Mertens' product formula

Tags: number-theory

Lamzouri, in "A bias in Mertens' product formula" [Lamzouri](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.3777.pdf), remarks that Diamond and Pintz ("Oscillation of Mertens' product formula") [Diamond and Pintz](http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2009__21_3_523_0.pdf) proved that
$$\sqrt{x}\left ( \prod_{p\leq x}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right )^{-1}-e^{\gamma }\log(x) \right )=\Omega _{\pm }\left ( \log_{3} x\right )$$
Diamond and Pintz didn't explicitly state this expression, but it appears to be a consequence of their Proposition 4.1.  Is the above expression unconditionally true, or is it conditional upon the Riemann Hypothesis?

I should have been more specific in my query.  I get that, for the non-R.H. case, Diamond and Pintz proved their

Theorem 1.1.  The quantity
$$\sqrt{x}\left ( \prod_{p\leq x}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right )^{-1}-e^{\gamma }\log(x) \right )$$

attains arbitrarily large positive and negative values as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

What I don't understand, is how, for the non-R.H. case, you get from this to the assertion that specifically $$\sqrt{x}\left ( \prod_{p\leq x}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right )^{-1}-e^{\gamma }\log(x) \right )=\Omega _{\pm }\left ( \log_{3} x\right ).$$

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the expression follows from Proposition 4.1 in Diamond and Pintz's paper. This is indeed an unconditional result. The proof is different depending on whether the Riemann hypothesis is false (the easier case—see Section 3 of that paper) or true (the more difficult case treated in Section 4), but since proofs exist in both cases, the final result is unconditional. This is a common strategy in comparative prime number theory, going back to Littlewood's proof that $\pi(x) - \mathop{\rm li}(x) = \Omega_\pm(\sqrt x\log\log\log x/\log x)$.